# Can swift classes use computed property arrays

Tags: swift

Is it possible to create a computed array property or does one need to create an overloaded function to accomplish this?

I.E. Could this be rewritten as a property

```
class myclass (
    private var myInternalArray[pvtstrct]()
init(){
 <loop building myInternalArray.insert(struct, at Index) .....>
}



func lfof(index: Int, value: String) {
    myInternalArray(index) = PrivateCoversionFromString(value)
}

func lfof(index: Int) -> String {
    return PrivateConversionToString(myInternalArray(index))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the functionality that you are looking for is in the section on the official Swift reference on [subscripts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Subscripts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH16-ID305).

Your first function is a setter and the second one is a getter. You could use a `subscript` to make it less awkward:

```
class MyClass {

    private var _privateArray: [SomeType]

    subscript(index: Int) -> String {
        get {
            return toString(_privateArray[index])
        }
        set(newValue) {
            _privateArray[index] = fromString(newValue)
        }
    }

    func fromString(value: String) -> SomeType {
        // The code that turns a string into SomeType
    }

    func toString(value: SomeType) -> String {
        // The code that turns SomeType into a string
    }
}
```

This piece of code was adapted from [The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.2)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH3-ID0).

Comment: I understand how get works in this context. The problem I have is obtaining both the index and value I need to pass to my internal func as this is a computed conversion to an internal array.

Comment: You should do the translations to and from the internal array in the `get { }` and `set { }` blocks. Maybe if you can elaborate on the context we can zero in what you need.

Comment: I expanded the example. I changed the names of the functions that you use, just to make it a bit more readable. I used `SomeType`, because I don't know the type of your private array.

Comment: Deleted my answer; this covers everything I had. @user6194042, regarding you comment on my earlier answer, make sure you read the link on subscripts. This isn't defining a function. Subscripts are their own language feature.

Comment: This looks more like a func definition than a property one but I see it in the guide now. Weird way to break what was looking really clean earlier on defining properties.....

Comment: @user6194042 I personally find it pretty clean, if you consider calculated properties. What does it break, exactly?

Comment: Still having some trouble figuring out how to implement subscripts. I have amended to code at the top to show the class init() in case that makes a difference